# Need to hide js file or minify it from the web browser after prod build in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, npm

After using `npm run build` cmd with the following script in package.json file in my React App,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false' && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

FYI: I am using windows machine.

The js code is not hiding from the browser stil I can see from the browser sources tab.
I am using spring application as backend.

Can anyone tell me how can I do hide js file or minify it after prod build.

Comment: Does changing `"build": "set 'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false' && react-scripts build",` to `"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"` has any effect?

Comment: are you running the app locally?

Comment: @Sambarilove Yes I have checked with that cmd but same issue.

Comment: @DavidGrosh Yes.

Comment: make sure you're running your app locally on the deployed mode(from the build file). also another way of checking what you have in the build folder, just check your code folder on your computer and not the source in the dev console

Comment: Yes I am running on the deployed mode.But I can't get your last point.

Comment: my point was to see what's in the build folder by not just checking the google dev console but checking your code editor if it's there. last thing, what's in the static folder?

Comment: I am not editing on build/static folder , whatever npm run build cmd generates that is present in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244310/discussion-between-david-grosh-and-subrata-ghosh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments that I receive form this post, I do the following and it resolve my problem,
1.Create .env file in my React project,

2.In this env file m I just put the following

```
BUILD_PATH='<location where I need to put the build content>'
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

3.Simply run `npm run build` it will generate the minified build and placed it mentioned location in the .env file.

Since it is minified the js content , So in DEV env , I just set `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true` to debug the code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to deploy the React app in order for the NODE_ENV to equal production, which would then run the app through the build folder, which GENERATE_SOURCEMAP is equal to false.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to hide those files would be to not include them at all.

what is it you are trying to accomplish by 'hiding' a file?

Are you trying to hide api keys  or other secrets?

Comment: Basically I don't want to show any js file from the web browser,because I can see the all actions and reducers and commponents are visiable from the browser sources file.